# Is it necessary to clear all cookies manually in frontend when a user logs out

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

Is it necessary to clear all cookies manually in frontend when a user logs out in case the server is unreachable after the user logged in?

Some people told me that all I have to do is tracing cookies on the server. That is confused me a lot. I set the expire time of the login session cookies with a long time(3 months) so the user does not need to input a password every day. But that's means once the user logs out failed and forget to clear cookies manually the next people who use that computer will have all rights of my true user.

Answer (score 1):

if you are worried about the users using public computers, then you could install a process in which you track the IP address where the user connects from, so if there is a new IP then ask the user if it is their computer or a public one, if theirs then set the 3 months expiration, if it is public then change it to 10-15 minutes or expire when they close the browser or something of that sort. Because like **@Ravishankar-s-r** mentioned, it has to be managed on the server side, which is where the cookie gets validated (accepted/rejected).

Comment: I come up with this question because I am comparing cookie-based authentication and jwt-based authentication. And I find it's totally not a problem for jwt-based authentication. Because the front end clear their token when users logged out.

Comment: yes, but on a public computer if someone were to install a cookie tracker/recorder then they will gain access if the session was not closed on the server side.

Comment: I think that's the browser's responsibility to prevent a tracker/recorder exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Nope, it's not necessary to clear the cookies on the browser. Cookies have to be managed on the server-side. Even if the cookies are present on the frontend after the user logs out. It's an invalid cookie as you have deleted the cookie session on the server-side when a user was logged out.**

Comment: What if the server-side is not reachable(for network reason or something else) when the client is requesting to logout.

Comment: The session will not be terminated in such cases and cookies will be still valid until it expires in server.